# Need Help on Selenium element selection

Tags: html, selenium, xpath

I have the below HTML code to create a checkbox, but XPath and CSS selectors do not recognize it. Is there another way to handle it?

```
<span class="checklist">
    <span class="">
        <input id="GenerateChargeFiles" type="checkbox" value="true" name="GenerateChargeFiles" data-val-required="The GenerateChargeFiles field is required." data-val="true">
        <input type="hidden" value="false" name="GenerateChargeFiles">
        <a class="checkbox-select">Check</a>
        <a class="checkbox-deselect">Uncheck</a>
    </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Well what selectors are you using? "Not recognising it" means what? It doesn't find it? Selenium tries an error? What error? If it finds it, what does it do? The `input` is hidden, so if you are trying to use *that*, it'll throw an error.

Comment: There is missing information here that is required for us to answer this question.  When you click the input element, I bet the DOM gets reloaded and there is more HTML there than you currently reveal.

Answer (score 0):

What XPath are you trying to use? The XPath `id('GenerateChargeFiles')` should work just fine. Below example uses Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("C:\\Users\\Tetrinity\\Documents\\test.html")
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("id('GenerateChargeFiles')")
element.click()
```

...where `test.html` contains:

```
<html><body>
<span class="checklist">
    <span class="">
        <input id="GenerateChargeFiles" type="checkbox" value="true" name="GenerateChargeFiles" data-val-required="The GenerateChargeFiles field is required." data-val="true">
        <input type="hidden" value="false" name="GenerateChargeFiles">
        <a class="checkbox-select">Check</a>
        <a class="checkbox-deselect">Uncheck</a>
    </span>
</span>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement checkBox = getDriver().findElement(By.id("GenerateChargeFiles"))
```